# Is copy constructor called when the temporary returning object is assigned to another object immediately

Tags: c++

i am having problem understanding how the output of this code comes out like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class three_d
{float x,y,z;
public:
    three_d(){x=y=z=0;cout<<"\n\tDefault Constructor";}
    three_d(float a,float b,float c){x=a;y=b;z=c;cout<<"\n\tOverloaded Constructor";}
    three_d(const three_d &obj){x=obj.x;y=obj.y;z=obj.z;cout<<"\n\tCopy Constructor";}
    three_d operator+(three_d op2);
    three_d operator=(three_d op2);
    void show();
    ~three_d(){cout<<"\n\tDestructor Working !!";}
};

three_d three_d::operator+(three_d op2)
{
    x=x+op2.x;
    y=y+op2.y;
    z=z+op2.z;
    return *this; 
}

three_d three_d::operator=(three_d op1)
{
    x=op1.x;
    y=op1.y;
    z=op1.z;
    return *this;
}

void three_d::show()
{
    cout<<"\n\n\tValues are : x="<<x<<" y="<<y<<" and z="<<z<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    three_d ob1(2.1,2,2.2);
    three_d ob2(1,1,1), ob3;
    ob3=ob1+ob2;
    ob1.show();
    ob2.show();
    ob3.show();

    return 0;
}
```

The output comes as :

```
1. Overloaded Constructor 
2. Overloaded Constructor
3. Default Constructor
4. Copy Constructor
5. Copy Constructor
6. Destructor Working !!
7. Copy Constructor
8. Destructor Working !!
9. Destructor Working !!
10. Values are : x=3.1 y=3 and z=3.2
11. Values are : x=1 y=1 and z=1
12. Values are : x=3.1 y=3 and z=3.2
13. Destructor Working !!
14. Destructor Working !!
15. Destructor Working !!
```

So my questions are:

- In the 5th line of output what is this copy constructor for? is it for *this pointer (but as it is a pointer i dont think it needs a copy constructor)? The fourth line is for object op2(i suppose) ?
- If above statement is true when overloading "=" why is only one copy constructor used(when it also have a returning value ?
- When is the temporary(returning) object destructed ?
- Please explain how the output is ordered like this.
- Even if i change the overloaded "+" to something like this :

  three_d three_d::operator+(three_d op2)
  {three_d temp;
  temp.x=x+op2.x;
  temp.y=y+op2.y;
  temp.z=z+op2.z;
  return temp; 
  }

the output of copy constructor for "=" remains same(though values will be changed) i.e only 1 copy constructor for "=". However I think there must be 2 copy constructors for "=" 1 for op1 object and other for *this . 
If i use simple assignment in main like :
 ob3=ob1;
 the copy constructor is called twice as expected. 
 
Please explain.

Comment: Whitespace is your friend.

Comment: Why don't you put some printing in your overloaded operators to help figuring the flow?

Comment: also, you should end your messages with newlines, not begin them with.

Comment: As noted in the comments on @Rsahu's answer, overloading `+` so it modifies its left-hand argument is a *terrible* idea. `+` should normally create and return a new value that's separate from either of its operands.

Comment: `this` is a pointer. `*this` is an object.

Comment: which compiler? Did you use `-fno-elide-constructors` to turn off [rvo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)?

Comment: @FredrickGauss VC++ 2010.

Comment: @WernerHenze, did you mean `T& T::operator=(const T& rhs);`

Comment: @FredrickGauss: You are right, I copied from the wrong web page :). Looking at the standard (§12.8, 17): copy assignment operators take exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`. Not written in the standard, but definitely a good idea: return a reference, not an object. Most useful copy assignment operator in my opinion: `T& T::operator=(const T& rhs);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to understand the statement, i think you should see it as;

> ob3.operator=(ob1.operator+(ob2));

`4. Copy Constructor` :
this is creating a temporary object from `ob2` because you calling `operator+` by value. Lets call this temporary **tmp2**.

`5. Copy Constructor` :
this is creating a temporary object from `ob1` becasue you are returning from `operator+` by value.Lets call this temporary **tmp1**.

`6. Destructor Working !!` :
when `operator+` finishes, temporary object **tmp2** destructed.

`-->Important note here` : `VC++` and `GCC` compilers interestingly passes temporary object **tmp1** returned from `operator+` to `operator=` by reference even `operator=` takes input by value(copy). this is why you dont see another copy constructor here. [This needs explanation by an expert]

`7. Copy Constructor` :
this is creating another temporary from `ob3` because you return from `operator=` by value. Lets call this last temporary **tmp3**.

`8. Destructor Working !!` :
when `operator+` finishes, `tmp1` is destructed.

`9. Destructor Working !!` :
when `operator+` finishes, `tmp3` is destructed at the end of the assignment.

When i see the result from `GCC` compiler, it is as following:

> 4.Copy Constructor
>   5.Copy Constructor
>   6.Copy Constructor
>   7.Destructor Working !!
>   8.Destructor Working !!
>   9.Destructor Working !!

And similar analysis that i have done as follows:

> 1. **tmp2** creation
> 2. **tmp1** creation
> 3. **tmp3** creation
> 4. **tmp3** destruction
> 5. **tmp1** destruction
> 6. **tmp2** destruction

**Note:** We are assuming you know the true way of defining `operator+` and `operator=` with signatures.(one is friend function taking two constant paramers, other returning by reference etc.)

Answer (score -1):

Both of your `operator+` and `operator=` return objects. They are copies of `*this`. Hence, the calls to the copy constructor.

If would like to avoid the call to the copy constructor, in order to avoid the cost of a copy, change those function to return a reference.

```
three_d const& three_d::operator+(three_d op2)
{
   x=x+op2.x;
   y=y+op2.y;
   z=z+op2.z;
   return *this; 
}

three_d const& three_d::operator=(three_d op1)
{
   x=op1.x;
   y=op1.y;
   z=op1.z;
   return *this;
}
```

**P.S.**

Your `operator+` function modifies the LHS of the operand. That is uncommon. In an expression

```
a = b + c;
```

you don't expect `b` to be changed. This is something to think about.

If you want to implement those functions in a well behaving way, you should change them to:

```
three_d three_d::operator+(three_d const& rhs) const
{
   three_d r(*this);
   r.x += rhs.x;
   r.y += rhs.y;
   r.z += rhs.z;
   return r; 
}

three_d& three_d::operator=(three_d const& rhs)
{
   if ( this != &rhs )
   {
      x = rhs.x;
      y = rhs.y;
      z = rhs.z;
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: `operator+` should not modify or `return *this` (by reference or otherwise) for a value-semantic type like this one is ostensibly intended to be: it should return a temporary by value.  `operator=` should generally return a ***non***-`const` reference to `*this*` so further modification is possible, as that's the semantics provided for in-built types.

Comment: This is generally a *bad* idea. You've defined `+` to alter its left-hand argument, so it acts like `+=` instead of `+`. That's the kind of code that convinced the Java designers that it was better to just not allow operator overloading at all.

Comment: @JerryCoffin because nobody could write an `.add()` method that does the same thing ... Sorry, I just think the argument "it could do something that you don't expect" is dumb. If you know the language supports operator overloading, you have to look at `a + b` as a method call. Thats the only difference.

Comment: @clcto: While I agree, the simple facts are that: 1) this sort of overload really is a terrible idea, and 2) it really is a reason they cited for why it was better to not allow overloading.